# How to select varchar column based on int min() function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

i want to select items that have minimum twu value for each tid seperately...my table name is reorganised

```
tid items      times twu
1   A           7   942
1   D           5   633
1   H           2   1020
2   S           4   551
3   F           4   871
3   B           2   641
4   M           1   665
4   N           7   950
4   Z           10  986
5   B           6   641
5   C           8   370
5   D           1   633
6   J           6   842
6   K           2   397
6   L           5   305
```

i tried this code

```
select tid,items,twu from REORGANISED where (TID,twu) in 
(select TID,min(twu)as TWU from REORGANISED group by tid);
```

it showed some error in where condition

Comment: please, provide the error message.

Comment: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.
This is my error comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get your desired result by joining your existing subquery and the original table itself. This solution works in all rdbms.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Reorganised a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            select TID,min(twu)as TWU 
            from REORGANISED 
            group by tid
        ) b ON  a.TID = b.TID
                AND a.TWU = b.TWU
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT tid,items,times,twu,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tid ORDER BY twu DESC) rn
FROM REORGANISED 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The `row_number` function should do the trick:

```
SELECT tid, items, times, twu
FROM   (SELECT tid, items, times, twu, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tid ORDER BY twu DESC) AS rn
        FROM   reorganised) y
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
SELECT  a.TID,ITEMS
FROM    Reorganised a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            select TID,min(twu)as TWU 
            from REORGANISED 
            group by tid
        ) b ON  a.TID = b.TID
                AND a.TWU = b.TWU
```